# C# .Net Framework portable установка

Tags: c#

Можно ли установить .Net Framework без установщика от Microsoft а своими руками? Копированием и т.д и как?

P.S: учитывая все косяки с реестром и т.д)

Comment: Проще взять .net core и под него приложение упаковать (3.0, если нужен декстоп).

Comment: Я могу вам скинуть вам видео, длительность которого ~час, там подробно рассказывают как сделать портативное приложение. В нем используется программа под названием Total Uninstall, которая делает "снимок" компьютера до установки приложения и после и этим методом можно отследить какие пути реестра задействованы, какие файлы устанавливаются. Но как по мне, такой подход для каких то системных библиотек не очень хорош. Это уже должно быть на совести пользователя, ставить ему .NET нужной версии или нет.

Comment: Предположу, что вы хотите сделать инсталлятор своего приложения, который автоматически установит нужную версию .NET Framework, если таковой нет на машине клиента? Открываете настройки своего проекта, вкладка Publish, кнопка Prerequisites..., пункт Download prerequisites from the same location as my application, OK, жмете Publish Now - далее следуете инструкции в сообщении. Оно?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так я и оставлю на совести пользователя, просто сейчас при запуске автономного установщика он либо в фоне либо меняет интерфейс, а когда в фоне то я например не могу оценить время установки

Comment: Значит ваш вопрос совершенно неверный и вы у нас спрашиваете совершенно не то, что в итоге хотите.